# Share folder (no matter what)

Tags: windows, wireless-networking, network-shares

Question is the following. How do i share a folder to any user in any network & any homegroup..

Question might seem weird, but.. I keep having problems with this, cos sometimes it works, and sometimes it doesn't not, and i don't understand why..

So, here's all the info.. I have:

- Windows 8.1 Pro Version 6.3.9600 (Legal version, if that changes anything)
- Avast Internet Security 2014 (again, legal version)
- Firewall enabled

I have shared a folder in my user directory, called "shared"

What i tried:

- disabling Antivirus
- disabling firewall

Here are all the shared info, i have created for it:

- http://screencast.com/t/WUW4qEEv35
- http://screencast.com/t/i3oo2M0Esy

All i want is to make this folder shared no matter what..
No matter what network i'm on, no matter how many users are connected to the same network, and any other reason.. and share it without a password..

I want this, cos i'm working at my office with different routers and different OS, that i have to share files with (usually the same files, that i keep modifying and other PC's (including linux & mac) test them..

And the stupid thing is, at random times (at least, i have no idea, why this happens) my pc becomes unnaccessible.. Meaning, others can see my PC, but cant see the folder, i share..

P.S. I don't want any other solutions, to share files.. I'm aware of them, and this is the best way FOR ME. I just want to know, why it doesn't work at some times, and fix it.

Comment: have you tried adding Everyone to the Security settings, too? Otherwise by default, security will be Administrators & named users on your machine, at best.

Comment: I already have "Everyone" in Security tab.. Still no luck

Comment: ah… was just a thought

Answer (score 0):

Windows generally limits the number of users that can access a share at once, depending on the license for your specific copy of windows.

To determine what your license allows, run winver from the start button's search box. Then click on on Microsoft Software License Terms. Look for the section called "Device Connections".

For example my personal version of windows 8 (from MSDN) says

> d.    Device connections. You may allow up to 20 other devices to access the software installed on the licensed computer for the purpose of using file services, print services, Internet information services, and Internet connection sharing and telephony services on the licensed computer. You may allow any number of devices to access the software on the licensed computer to synchronize data between devices. This section does not mean, however, that you have the right to install the software, or use the primary function of the software (other than the features listed in this section), on any of these other devices.

Comment: Can you give a more detailed description of the linked content, and explain how it relates to the question? This will help ensure that this answer remains useful in the event the linked page goes offline.

Comment: Sure, will edit.

Comment: In Software  License Terms, section 3 is "3. Choice of Law" and has no sub-sections.. :(

Comment: You are correct, stuff moved. Will edit.